# Delete everything BUT charts in PPT presentation?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to delete everything in my powerpoint presentation, except the charts that are already there. I have been searching for day with no avail.

I did however find this VBA that deletes all charts. Unfortunately, it is the opposite of what I am trying to achieve. I have tried using VBA found in other code and adding it, but nothing helps. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Sub RemoveAllCharts()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim i, num

'Loop Through Each Slide in ActivePresentation   
  For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    num = sld.Shapes.Count
    For i = num To 1 Step -1
        If sld.Shapes(i).HasChart Then
            sld.Shapes(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
  Next sld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to add a `Not` to achieve this, i.e. change

```
If sld.Shapes(i).HasChart Then
```

to

```
If Not sld.Shapes(i).HasChart Then
```

---

```
Sub RemoveAllButCharts()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim i As Long, num As Long

    'Loop Through Each Slide in ActivePresentation
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        num = sld.Shapes.Count
        For i = num To 1 Step -1
            If Not sld.Shapes(i).HasChart Then
                sld.Shapes(i).Delete
            End If
        Next i
     Next sld
End Sub
```